# How can i use fft to find the maximum frequency of a periodic signal?

Tags: matlab, max, fft, frequency

I'm trying to find the maximum frequency of a periodic signal in Matlab and as i know when you convert a periodic signal to the frequency spectrum you get only delta functions however i get a few curves between the produced delta functions. Here is the code :

```
 t=[-0.02:10^-3:0.02];
 s=5.*(1+cos(2*pi*10*t)).*cos(2*pi*100*t);
 figure, subplot(211),    plot(t,s);
 y=fft(s);
 subplot(212), plot(t,y);
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you use `plot(t, abs(y))`? also, your time vector is too short to see the effect of the smaller frequency. Try for example `t=[-0.02:10^-3:0.2];`

Comment: I did but i still get small curves not delta functions exclusively

Comment: @bill because A) the transform is discrete, and B) you're connecting the points with lines. Mostly A though.

Comment: Also, `t` is not really the axis you want to be plotting `y` against.

Comment: @LuisMendo, you meant `t=[-0.2:10^-3:0.2];` ? Right? Because with `t=[-0.02:10^-3:0.2];`, we have shifted the whole plot.

Comment: @bill You won't usually see (discrete) deltas with a DFT. The original signal is finite, so the ideal deltas get smeared

Comment: @JoeyMallone Probably yes, depending on what the OP wants. My point was just to make time span larger

Comment: Yes I'm sorry   that's what i meant.

Comment: How can i get only deltas however ? I'm trying to find the maximum frequency of the signal above .

Comment: _"how to get only deltas"_, use `stem` instead of `plot`, if you are only interested in the appearance. But for true deltas there are other considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code-snippet to help you understand how to get the frequency-spectrum using *fft* in `matlab`.

Things to remember are:

1. You need to decide on a sampling frequency, which should be high enough, as per the Nyquist Criterion (You need the number of samples, at least more than twice the highest frequency or else we will have aliasing). That means, fs in this example cannot be below `2 * 110`. Better to have it even higher to see a have a better appearance of the signal.
2. For a real signal, what you want is the power-spectrum obtained as the square of the absolute of the output of the fft() function. The imaginary part, which contains the phase should contain nothing but noise. (I didn't plot the phase here, but you can do this to check for yourself.)
3. Finally, we need to use `fftshift` to shift the signal such that we get the mirrored spectrum around the zero-frequency.
4. The peaks would be at the correct frequencies. Now considering only the positive frequencies, as you can see, we have the largest peak at 100Hz and two further lobs around `100Hz +- 10Hz` i.e. 90Hz and 110Hz.

Apparently, *110Hz* is the highest frequency, in your example.

**The code:**

```
fs = 500; % sampling frequency - Should be high enough! Remember Nyquist!

 t=[-.2:1/fs:.2];
 s= 5.*(1+cos(2*pi*10*t)).*cos(2*pi*100*t);
 figure, subplot(311),    plot(t,s);

 n = length(s);
 y=fft(s);


 f = (0:n-1)*(fs/n); % frequency range
 power = abs(y).^2/n;
 subplot(312), plot(f, power);

 Y = fftshift(y);
 fshift = (-n/2:n/2-1)*(fs/n); % zero-centered frequency range

 powershift = abs(Y).^2/n;
 subplot(313), plot(fshift, powershift);
```

**The output plots:**

1. The first plot is the signal in the time domain
2. The signal in the frequency domain
3. The shifted fft signal
   [image]

Comment: Thank you very much i found the same result earlier on paper.